# Find the characteristic of the following field $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

Could someone please verify whether my solution is fine?

> Consider the following field:
>
> $F=\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
>  1& 0\\ 
>  0& 1
> \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 1\\ 
>  1& 0
> \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 &1 \\ 
> 1 & 1
> \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
>  0&0 \\ 
> 0 &0 
> \end{bmatrix} \right \}$
>
> with entries from $\Bbb{Z}_{2}$. Find the characteristic of $F$.

Since $I\in F$ and for any $A\in F$, $AI=IA=A$, then $F$ has identity $I$.

Since $2\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2&0 \\ 
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ (because $2\equiv 0$ (mod $2$)), then $\operatorname{char}(F)=|I|=2$.

Comment: If a field has $p^n$ elements, with $p$ a prime, then it has characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. But it would have been faster to observe that, for any $M\in F$, $M+M=0$.